# Parsing JSON from HTML

Tags: html, node.js, jsdom

Using NodeJS I would like to parse a variable defined in JSON, which is embeded in HTML of 3rd party website. What is the easiest way to get mentioned variable from HTML?

Chunk of HTML from which I would like to extract mentioned JS can be seen bellow:

```html
...
<footer>
  <div>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
            {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/","image":"https:\/\/assets.domain.com\/img\/facebook\/stuf.png","name":"Home"}}]}
    </script>
    <script>
        var API_URL = ["https:\/\/api1.domain.com\/api","https:\/\/api2.domain.com\/api","https:\/\/api3.domain.com\/api"],
    </script>
  </div>
</footer>
...
```

The following HTML is parsed from XY website using NodeJS. I would like to avoid using `eval()`.

I tried with JSDOM, but I didn't know how to select mentioned `<script>`. Is regex the only solution?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're asking of. Provide some minimum example, please.

Comment: I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you provided, the selector will be: `footer>div>script:nth-child(2)`.
Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: I guess I can blame it on Friday, didn't even consider that script is part of DOM... ty